# C# CSVHelper libary - Truncating decimal places when writing CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I'm writing a script to pull some data from a SQL database and write it to a .csv file.

I'm struggling retaining the decimal digits for a Decimal type field.

When the value is 10.0000, it's truncated to display 10 in the CSV. I need it to always display 2 decimal places.

Here is what I have so far

```
CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
config.ShouldQuote = args => true;

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("..\\..\\..\\CSVs\\test.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer,config))
{
    csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<double?>(new TypeConverterOptions
    {
        Formats = new string[] { "F" },
        NumberStyles = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
        
    });

    csv.WriteRecords(customerPrices);
}
```

Where customer prices is a list of CustomerPrice class.

```
    public class CustomerPrice
    {
        public string? PriceStatus { get; set; }
        public string? BGRItem { get; set; }
        public string? CustomerNumber { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Category { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal FuturePrice { get; set; }
        public string? UOM { get; set; }
        public decimal MinQty { get; set; }

        [Format("MM/dd/yyyy")]
        public DateTime Effective { get; set; }

        [Format("MM/dd/yyyy")]
        public DateTime LastSale { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the generated CSV which looks like this:
[image: CSV Example]

```
"PriceStatus","BGRItem","CustomerNumber","Description","Category","CurrentPrice","FuturePrice","UOM","MinQty","Effective","LastSale"
"UNCHANGED","162618","162618","SHOWA 7570PF GREEN 4 MIL DISP. NITRILE GLOVE SZ XL (100 EACH/BOX - 20 BOXES/CASE)","Disposable Gloves","10.0000","10.0000","BOX","1.00","10/03/2022","01/01/1753"
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `AddOptions<decimal>` instead of `AddOptions<double?>`?

Comment: your csv seems to have decimal places your view in Excel seems not. Looks like an Excel problem and not like a csv creation problem.

Comment: Correct @MathiasR.Jessen. Result is still the same

Comment: Good point @Ralf . As long as there isn't anything I can do for the csv to be interpreted differently....sounds like there is nothing else I can do...